# r.in.lidar Error: 'Raster map not found' in QGIS 2.18.14 GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, lidar, las

First of all I would like to say, that I have checked all the open threads (with almost the same title) about r.in.lidar errors and in general GRASS and it's "raster map not found" errors within QGIS 2.18.x.

The r.in.lidar in QGIS 2.18.14 and in GRASS 7.0.3 in Linux Mint and Windows 10 do the same error when running the tool:

```
Algorithm r.in.lidar - Creates a raster map from LAS LiDAR points using univariate statistics. starting...
g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
g.region n=92000.0 s=91000.0 e=396000.0 w=395000.0 res=1
r.in.lidar input="/home/alen/Desktop/TM_395_91.laz" method=mean type=FCELL zscale="1" percent="100" resolution="1" -e -o output=output412a4072b5e749b8b5eaa46a1e1a183f --overwrite
g.region raster=output412a4072b5e749b8b5eaa46a1e1a183f
r.out.gdal --overwrite -c createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=output412a4072b5e749b8b5eaa46a1e1a183f output="/home/alen/Desktop/obmocje.tif"
Cleaning up temporary files... 
Starting GRASS GIS... 
Executing '/home/alen/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' ... 
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default 
Projection information updated 
ERROR: Unable to open file 
ERROR: Raster map not found 
ERROR: Raster map or group not found 
Execution of '/home/alen/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' finished. 
Cleaning up temporary files... 
Cleaning up temporary files... 
Starting GRASS GIS... 
Executing '/home/alen/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' ... 
ERROR: Raster map not found 
ERROR: Raster map or group not found 
Execution of '/home/alen/.qgis2//processing/grass7_batch_job.sh' finished. 
Cleaning up temporary files..
```

For Windows 10 I tried for both the OSGeo4W install and the direct install. I tried it also with QGIS 2.16.x and 2.14.x for both the OS. In Linux Mint I apt-get autoremoved/autocleaned always after. 
In Windows 10, if I install GRASS 7.2.2 separately and run the tool from it, it works well. I tried to reconnect QGIS with the separate GRASS install, but it does the same error again.

It worked until a few updates ago:
it works well in QGIS 2.18.5 with GRASS 7.2.0.

I noticed that also other r.* GRASS tools don't work anymore.

How can I make r.in.lidar work from QGIS?

Comment: Can you test if the original LAZ filew is readable? The first error "Unable to open file" is suspicious. Please do `gdalinfo /home/alen/Desktop/TM_395_91.laz`. Can you try running the commands one by one in a GRASS terminal?

Comment: @Micha Yes, the file is readable and I have outputs. As I wrote, in Windows 10, if I install GRASS 7.2.2 separately and run the tool from it, it works well (generates the product i want). It runs in GRASS separately via cmd and GUI, but just in Windows, which is strange. I used to use the QGIS integrated tool until a few months ago, now it seems that an update crashed things.

Comment: @Micha gdalinfo does an "ERROR 4: `/home/mazinga/Downloads/TMR_395_91.laz' not recognized as a supported file format." But gdalinfo deosn't niether support LAS / LAZ files. http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html

Comment: Yes, I see you're right. Sorry for misleading.  Nevertheless, r.in.lidar does work for me. I believe It's compiled with the older libLAS (and GDAL is not).

Comment: It works also for me with QGIS 2.18.5 and GRASS 7.2.0. I really hope "they" fix it soon. Thanks for your comments, regards.

Comment: It seems you already confirmed it is a bug. Have you reported it to QGIS developers (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because _"this is a bug report and not a question for GIS.SE"_; as recommended in our GIS Meta post [What should we do with bug reports?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/what-should-we-do-with-bug-reports).

Comment: Yes, I have reported it and the possible answer to this question is also a bug fix, so I don't agree with you... But yes, If the rules are such, then this remains.