# Which QGIS installation for Windows comes with r.in.lidar?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation, lidar

I am running QGIS 2.18.14 (QGIS code revision: ff83b9a479) on a windows 7 machine, it comes with GRASS 7.2.2 (Code Revision r71496), but it does not come with r.in.lidar. I have noticed QGIS 2.18.16.1 has the same problem and it shares the same GRASS 7.2.2 (Code Revision r71496).

I know there were some issues with it and later solved as I read [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263320/r-in-lidar-error-raster-map-not-found-in-qgis-2-18-14-grass), I also certailny used it short ago in 2017, so I wonder which version should I go for before starting the always risky attempt of a new installation.

Comment: Do you want to use GRASS via processing, or with the GRASS plugin?

Comment: Any of them... or even both, the thing is to have only one installation because I have no admin rights and every request is a new ticket in a queue

Comment: It seems that OSGEO4W and standalone 2.18.17 both have what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The standalone installer for windows 64 bit of **GRASS GIS 7.4.0 (current stable)** comes with v.in.lidar and r.in.lidar (tested!)
- The standalone installers from OSGeo4W packages for windows 64 bit **QGIS 2.18.17 'Las Palmas'** comes with GRASS GIS 7.4.0 (but I have not tested yet)