# access r.in.lidar through pyGIS console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, lidar, lastools

How can I access the r.in.lidar algo with the pyqgis console? i tried to import processing and algolist but r.in.liad under the GRASS GIS algo does not get listed. Also Checked the options iunder toolbox processing to activate the GRASSGIS 7 commands

Answer (score 2):

You might miss it in the installation. I noticed it in my installation and I asked about: [Which QGIS installation for Windows comes with r.in.lidar?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273002/which-qgis-installation-for-windows-comes-with-r-in-lidar)

Comment: GRASSGIS7 commands is the processing tools. Using windows 10. I was able to figure it out. Hopefully the pyqgis code runs well. Is batch process possible through pyQGIS?