# Choosing QGIS download to install?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.14

The organisation I've just started at uses QGIS 2.14 Essen & I want to download it to practice at home on my Win 64 Home Premium machine. I've found an index of exe files (download.osgeo.org/qgis/win64/) but have no idea which one I should download.

e.g. what's the difference between this one *QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.22-1-Setup-x86_64.exe* & this one *QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.22-1-Setup-x86_64.exe.md5sum*? What's the md5sum part mean?

Answer (score 6):

The `.md5sum` file looks like this: 

`7019f34346e4cbeca68fae5681107ed0 *QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.0.1-1-Setup-x86_64.exe`

It is a mechanism to confirm no one has tampered with the file and that it has downloaded correctly. So you want to download `QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.22-1-Setup-x86_64.exe`.
 Then if you want to confirm it hasn't been altered and is all there you can compute the md5sum hash for it independently and compare it to the value in `QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.22-1-Setup-x86_64.exe.md5sum`. There are plenty of guides explaining how, eg: https://www.lifewire.com/validate-md5-checksum-file-4037391

Answer (score 4):

The md5sum is just to make sure your downloaded installation file is complete, and not corrupted. See [md5sum on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) for how it works. Download both, then use the md5sum file to check the installation file.

You probably should consider moving ahead to version 2.18.x, the current "stable".

Comment: If I was learning independently I'd be using the latest stable version but for now, as I'm a beginner, I'll stick with the same one I'm going to be using at work.

Comment: Based on my own experience and I would recommend to switch to the current stable, which is not always free of troubles either. So far I have tried 2.18.17 and it has the components I needed (QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.18.17-1-Setup-x86_64.exe). See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273002/which-qgis-installation-for-windows-comes-with-r-in-lidar/273917#273917

Answer (score 2):

you should download QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.22-1-Setup-x86_64.exe
the QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.22-1-Setup-x86_64.exe.md5sum file is just
there for you to verify the 'checksum' of the .exe files integrity.

if i've missed the mark on the .md5sum part, can someone just rectify.